# JScrollPane (Jquery plugin) not working in my site

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I cannot to use JscrollPane, in my class (product-description_r) I can't see my custom scrollbar... any sugegsts?

I have include

js:
http://www.siragusafood.com/templates/mod/src/scrollbar.js

css:
http://www.siragusafood.com/templates/mod/css/scrollbar.css

and most important this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){           
            jQuery('.product-description_r').jScrollPane(); 
   });
</script>
```

my code is here:

http://www.siragusafood.com/index.php/prodotti-shop/confetture/marmellata-mandarino-detail?showall=1